# Coldfusion filter for grid on last name, won't allow collection of records

Tags: java, mysql, coldfusion

I have a coldfusion web page that is using a filter to dynamically display data on the cfgrid.  I'm binding the data and displaying from two functions in a cfc file.  Below is the code from the main file that is using the binding methods:

```
<cfform name="postServices" method="post" action="inService02list_v2.cfm?post=1" >

<label>Last Name Search: </label><cfinput type="text" name="filter" id="filter" width="200;" style="border-color:##F60; border-width:medium;" />

    <cfgrid name="SelectStuff" format="html" width="785" height="450" selectmode="edit" bind="cfc:_listings.getStudentData({cfgridpage},{cfgridpagesize},{cfgridsortcolumn},{cfgridsortdirection},{filter@keyup})" bindonload="true" onchange="cfc:_listings.editF({cfgridaction},{cfgridrow},{cfgridchanged})">

     <cfgridcolumn name="GUID" header="Select"  type="boolean"
                        values="1" display="yes" select="yes">
<cfgridcolumn name="INSERT_ID" header="GUID" width="80" select="no">

<cfgridcolumn name="STU_LAST" header="Last" width="100" select="no">
<cfgridcolumn name="STU_FIRST" header="First" width="80" select="no" >
 <cfgridcolumn name="STU_MIDDLE" header="Middle" width="40" select="no" >
   <cfgridcolumn name="CAMPUS" header="Campus" width="120" select="no" >
  <cfgridcolumn name="GRADE" header="Grade Level" width="100" select="no"> 

  </cfgrid>
</cfform>
```

And below are the methods from the cfc file:

```
<cfcomponent>

<!--- Function to display filtered data --->

    <cffunction name="editF" access="remote" output="true" returntype="Any"> 
        <cfargument name="gridaction" type="string" required="yes"> 
       <cfargument name="gridrow" type="struct" required="yes"> 
       <cfargument name="gridchanged" type="struct" required="yes"> 
       <!--- Local variables ---> 
       <cfset var value=""> 
       <!--- Process gridaction ---> 
       <cfswitch expression="#ARGUMENTS.gridaction#"> 


     <!--- Process updates ---> 
          <cfcase value="U"> 
             <!--- Get column name and value ---> 
             <cfset colname=StructKeyList(ARGUMENTS.gridchanged)> 
             <cfset value=ARGUMENTS.gridchanged[colname]> 

          </cfcase> 
       </cfswitch> 
    </cffunction>

<!--- FUNCTION TO FILTER GRID --->    

<cffunction name="getstudentdata" access="remote" output="false" returntype="Any"> 
<cfargument name="page" required="false" default="1" type="Numeric" /> 
<cfargument name="pagesize" required="false"
default="1000" type="Numeric" /> 
<cfargument name="sortcolumn" required="false" default="" type="string" /> 
<cfargument name="sortdir" required="false" default="ASC" type="string" /> 
<cfargument name="filter" required="false" default="" type="String" />


<cfstoredproc datasource="DESO_DB" procedure="getStudents">
<cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" dbvarname="inSchool" value="#SESSION.auth.campus#">
<cfprocresult name="q">
</cfstoredproc>

<cfset queryAddColumn(q, "INSERT_ID", arrayNew(1))>

<cfloop query="q">
   <cfset querySetCell(q, "INSERT_ID", #GUID#, currentrow)>
</cfloop>

<cfif Len(#arguments.filter#) GTE 2>
 <cfset CapFirst = UCase(left(#arguments.filter#,1)) & Right(#arguments.filter#,Len(#arguments.filter#)-1)>
 <cfelse>
<cfset CapFirst = #arguments.filter#>
</cfif> 

<cfquery name="q" dbtype="query"> 
select * from q 
where STU_LAST like <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" 
value="%#arguments.filter#%" /> 
OR 
STU_LAST like <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" 
value="%#UCASE(arguments.filter)#%" /> 
OR 
 STU_LAST like <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" 
value="%#CapFirst#%" /> 
OR 
STU_LAST like <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" 
value="%#UCASE(CapFirst)#%" /> 

<cfif len(trim(arguments.sortcolumn))>
            order by #arguments.sortcolumn# #arguments.sortdir#
</cfif>


</cfquery>

<cfreturn queryConvertForGrid(q,'1','1000') /> 

</cffunction> 

</cfcomponent>
```

The problem I'm having, is that I cannot insert these records to an array that stores into the database, I'm getting an error message: "You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class java.lang.String as a structure with members."  Below are the lines of code that are throwing this error:

```
<cfif #lookForDupsAttRet.RecordCount# EQ 0 AND #ArrayLen(SELECTSTUFF.INSERT_ID)# NEQ 0>    

<cfloop array="#SELECTSTUFF.INSERT_ID#" index="i">

<cfif #ArrayLen(SELECTSTUFF.INSERT_ID)# EQ 0>
```

Before I added the filter, you would be able to select the records you wanted and submit to database.  The cfgrid was using a query instead of data that has a bind.  Maybe someone on here can help guide me as to how I can get these records inserted into the database while still using a filter for lookup on student last name.

Thanks,

Comment: You don't need to check the length of the SELECTSTUFF.INSERT_ID array inside your loop. You've already checked it outside the loop. You also don't need the #s in anything but `cfloop array="#SELECTSTUFF.INSERT_ID#"` and `order by #arguments.sortcolumn# #arguments.sortdir#'. Lastly, watch out for that ORDER BY clause. It is very injectable. Validate sortcolumn and sortdir before you use them (preferably not directly from an argument).   Then CFDUMP your SELECTSTUFF.INSERT_ID array? That should tell you if it's an array that can be iterated.

Comment: Thanks for the response Shawn, I'll use a CFDUMP on SELECTSTUFF.INSERT_ID to see if it can be iterated and check my ORDER BY clause.